# Installing cordova and ionic, error: ECONNRESET, no solution works

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I am trying install ionic with `npm install -g cordova ionic` on my notebook with windows 7 x64, but no matter what I do returned an error **ECONNRESET**. I tried using various solutions here the stackoverflow but could not.

I'm trying:
`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`. also I uninstalled it x64 and install the x84, nothing works.

[npm-degub](https://jsfiddle.net/6ykqko2k/1/). *This very large, the only place I could put in was jsFiddle.

C:\Users\User>node -v
v4.2.2

C:\Users\User>npm -v
2.14.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly out of nowhere he came back to work and managed to install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running behind a proxy server? Are you able to install other node packages? No need to set the registry as this is the default one.

Comment: What means running behind a proxy server? i installed npm live-server and it worked!

Comment: try to run `npm update -g npm` and try installing again after it. Looks like there is a problem from the last day https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8196